# Should i create a new Type for Collection in FluentValidation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, validation, fluentvalidation

I am trying to find if there is way available in FluentValidation which allows a collection to be validated for a Validator at Root Level.

For e.g. As shown below, a validator is available for `CustomerValidator` for a class `Customer`. 
    using FluentValidation;

```
public class CustomerValidator: AbstractValidator<Customer> {
  public CustomerValidator() {
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Surname).NotEmpty();
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Forename).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please specify a first name");
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Discount).NotEqual(0).When(customer => customer.HasDiscount);
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Address).Length(20, 250);
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Postcode).Must(BeAValidPostcode).WithMessage("Please specify a valid postcode");
  }

  private bool BeAValidPostcode(string postcode) {
    // custom postcode validating logic goes here
  }
}

Customer customer = new Customer();
CustomerValidator validator = new CustomerValidator();
ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(customer);

bool validationSucceeded = results.IsValid;
IList<ValidationFailure> failures = results.Errors;
```

**The question is, If i have a `List<Customer>` and i need to validate that atleast one customer should have `Surname` how do i validate the list.** Is there a out of box functinality available in fluentvalidation, at this time, i can think either of following ways. *Can you suggest what can be best approach ?*

**1.** Iterating in a loop and then calling the validate method for each Customer.

```
 List<ValidationResult> listOfValidationErrors = List<ValidationResult>();
 // listCustomer is of type List<Customer>
 foreach (var customer in listCustomer)
 {
     CustomerValidator validator = new CustomerValidator();
     listOfValidationErrors.Add(validator.Validate(customer);
 }
```

**2.** Create a new collection class for Customer collection `CustomerCollection` and then create a validator class `CustomerCollectionValidator`

```
    public class CustomerCollection
    {
        public List<Customer> ListOfCustomers { get; set; }

        public CustomerCollection(List<Customer> listOfCustomers )
        {
            this.ListOfCustomers = listOfCustomers ;
        }
    }
```

and then Validator class

```
public class CustomerCollectionValidator: CompositeValidator<CustomerCollection>
    {
        public CustomerCollectionValidator()
        {

            RuleFor(x => x.ListOfCustomers)
                    .Must(ShouldHaveOneSurName)
                    .WithMessage("Should have one Surname in list");

            RuleForEach(x => x.ListOfCustomers).SetValidator<CustomerValidator>();

        }

        public bool ShouldHaveOneSurName(List<Customer> lstCustomers)
        {
            if (lstCustomers== null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return lstCustomers.Any(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.SurName);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from the above 2 methods, Jeremy Skinner suggested another method [here](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/issues/241), which uses inheritance from  `AbstractValidator<List<Customer>>` .  This didn't work with original code, but Jeremy committed the change in Fluent Validation source code in version 6.3 [here](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation).

Following code presents the 3rd way for doing the validation for Root  Level collection.

```
public class CustomerCollectionValidator : AbstractValidator<List<Customer>> {
  public CustomerCollectionValidator() {
     RuleFor(list => list).SetCollectionValidator(new CustomerValidator());
  }
}
```